# Using Jersey REST with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, servlets, jersey

As I understand App Engine loads an instance of a Servlet when requested if it is not already in memory. This means that requests that trigger a new instance of a Servlet will be slower to serve a request.

If I use Jersey with GAE I assume there is only the one bloated Jersey Servlet that needs to be instantiated on each request requiring a new instance.

Surely this will make these requests even slower since the Jersey Servlet to be loaded is much larger than if you use many seperate Servlets?

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: [Warmup requests] (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Warmup_requests) can be used to solve the slow response time because of code being loaded into a new instance. Can you please clarify regarding Jersey Servlet vs many separate Servlets?

Comment: Thank you. I am actually using a warmup request to cache some stuff, but my concern is more with the loading of the Jersey Servlet which is understandably quite 'large' since it is really a single servlet that maps requests to responses, whereas without jersey you have a different `HttpServlet` for each request / response.